# Flyway servlet initialization

Tags: flyway

Liquibase has a servlet option to initialize the database. http://liquibase.org/manual/servlet_listener

Is there an example of this for Flyway? Or, better yet a working servlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really want, is to run `flyway.migrate()` on startup. This can be accomplished through a variety of ways, Servlet Listeners being one of them.

There is no servlet listener included out of the box, but it's trivial to roll your own.

It should look something like this:

```java
@WebListener
public class FlywayListener implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
        flyway.setDataSource(...);
        flyway.migrate();
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    }
}
```

A class implementing the [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) interface is called [before](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized-javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent-) the first servlet (or filter) invocation and [after](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextDestroyed-javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent-) the last. The [`@WebListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html) annotation is one way to inform your Servlet container of your intended listener. For more info, see [this Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafi.html) and [search Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ServletContextListener).

Comment: haven't gotten chance to integrate, when I do I'll post the web.xml I use.

Comment: my next question is where in the world does one obtain DataSource from JPA?

Comment: For more info on `ServletContextListener`, see [my Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36588744/642706) to [Hook for my Vaadin web app starting and stopping?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36588743/642706). ( [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/) is a Servlet framework; my Answer applies to any Servlet situation. ) The trick comes in trying to halt your web app if Flyway encounters a problem. See my Question, [Stop launch of web app from `ServletContextListener` method `contextInitialized`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36611392/642706). The Servlet spec does not clearly provide for such interruption.